# RegEx for Telephone # with country code included

Tags: regex, validation

I need to validate a telephone number in the following format

```
xx-xxx-xxxxxx
```

`x` can only be a digit and all `x` can't be zero.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `java` *and* `javascript`?

Comment: Good tutorial for regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ Try it, the expression you are looking for is not difficult.

Comment: next time, make some kind of attempt in your question

Answer (score 2):

```
[1-9]\d-\d{3}-\d{6}
```

Assuming only the first digit needs to be non-zero.

```
[1-9]{2}-[1-9]{3}-[1-9]{6}
```

if none of the digits can be zero.

Anchor with `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

x can only be a digit and **all** x can't be zero.

```
^(?!0{2})[0-9]{2}-(?!0{3})[0-9]{3}-(?!0{6})[0-9]{6}$
```

It will not accept all zero country code or all zero telephone number.